# How to log username logging into ubuntu PPTP service

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, pptp

I need to log every connection made into our PPTP daemon. I can find the IP address of the client connection from `/var/log/daemon.log`, but can't find the username that is used to login.

When using L2TP, I can find the username from parsing `/var/log/syslog`, but can't find it for PPTP connections.

Any ideas how I can find it?